# Entire Headerline acts as link and not only where the text is

Tags: html, css, header

Sorry if I'm doing something wrong here, I'm kinda new to coding and this website.

Anyways, here goes

I want to implement ads into my website on the left and right of the centered "Logo" on top. However, the Header Logo acts as a link for the entire line in the size of the text which makes that impossible to implement / impossible to click on the ads.

Here's the header line

```
  <div class="container">
     <a href="/index.html" style="text-decoration: none"><div style="font-family: Conv_5STAR_League; font-size:20px"><h1
 align="center"><span style="color:gold">LoL</span><span
 style="color:white">Chromas</span></h1></div></a>
     <div style="text-align: center"><img src="./Aatrox Chromas_files/SYozsnx.png" alt="Aatrox"; style= "width= 150"></div>
     <h1 class="strokeme" style="text-align: center; font-family: Conv_5STAR_League;color: white">Aatrox</h1>
```

I would really appreciate any help I can get on this, even if it's a "noob" problem, as said, I'm still really new to this and couldn't find a solution on google

Thank you all and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` - a block element that occupies 100% of the width, so was clickable link across the width

and why use extra markup - you can do it easily

http://jsfiddle.net/v0b3um4p/

```css
h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Conv_5STAR_League; 
    font-size:20px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <h1><a href="/index.html" class="" style="text-decoration: none"><span style="color:gold">LoL</span><span
 style="color:white">Chromas</span></a>
    </h1>
     <div style="text-align: center"><img src="./Aatrox Chromas_files/SYozsnx.png" alt="Aatrox"; style= "width= 150"></div>
     <h1 class="strokeme" style="text-align: center; font-family: Conv_5STAR_League;color: white">Aatrox</h1>
```

Comment: instead of just giving him the code, expand your answer to explain why he should do this in comparison to the problem he's faced with now.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! That fixed it, though the Font is not applied anymore, how do I resolve that?

Comment: add to h1 - font-family: Conv_5STAR_League; font-size:20px